# Prolog:simple family relation

Tags: prolog, logic, family-tree

I am learning Prolog and what i want is to do a simple "calculation"(i dont know how its called in Prolog) of the members of a simle family.

For example i have:

```
 1)father of steve is petter
 2)brother steve is john
 3)A person is a son to a Father when the brother of the person has  as father the Father
```

(it seems funny and completely out of logic  when its out of my mind :)  )

```
father(steve,petter).
brother(john,steve).
father(X,Y):-brother(X,Z),father(Z,Y)).
```

and my question is who is the father of john(the correct awnser would be petter)

```
?-father(john,X).
```

But it always giving me false.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter `father(john, X).`, it starts by trying to find a `Z` such that `brother(john, Z)` is true. No such `Z` exists, so it returns false.

Note that `brother(steve, john)` does not imply `brother(john, steve)` unless you tell Prolog that it should.

Comment: Well.in the tutorial i was reading the something(1,2) was saying could be interpreted and as something(2,1) , but i guess it was meaning only by the programmer not by Prolog ...my fault... But even if i change them i am getting false again , even when i put both of the cases .Whats the correct way?

Comment: @SteveL I think that what you read meant that you can encode phrases like `Mike plays with a dog` either as `plays(mike, dog)` or `plays(dog,mike)`. But once you choose an interpretation you have to stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

```
father(steve,petter).
brother(john,steve).
whoisfather(X,Y):-brother(X,Z),father(Z,Y).
?- whoisfather(john,X).
X = petter.
```

instead of

```
father(steve,petter).
brother(john,steve).
father(X,Y):-brother(X,Z),father(Z,Y)).
?- father(john,X).
false.
```

See comments

Comment: no, actually, your original code works. You just have one extra parenthesis there, a typo. When I run it, I get `2 ?- father(john,X).` ==> `X = petter ;` (here I press `;`) and then `No`.

Comment: lol . how did i miss that omg.This *** litle mistakes that gets you crazy. Thanks